# Azure Application insights -- availability percentage based on ResultCode

Tags: azure-application-insights, dashboard, azure-monitoring, availability

I am trying to get Availability percentage based on ResultCode , Below is my Query, Can some one help finding the correct one ?

```
requests
| where cloud_RoleName contains "somename"
| where client_Type != "Browser" and name !contains "GET"
| where resultCode !in (400,401,403,404,500,502)
| summarize count=sum(itemCount)
| project Percentage= (todouble((count) * 100 / todouble(count))
```

Comment: Hello, when somebody comment / answer your question, you'd better giving some response, like the solution works or not or accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Requests
| where cloud_RoleName contains "somename"
| where client_Type != "Browser" and name !contains "GET"
| summarize total=count()
| extend a = "a"
| join 
(   Requests
    | where cloud_RoleName contains "somename"
    | where client_Type != "Browser" and name !contains "GET"
    | where resultCode !in (400,401,403,404,500,502)
    | summarize success=count()
    | extend a = "a"
) on a
| project Percentage = success*100/todouble(total)
```